# grub2 (actually burg) can't see partitions on GPT external hdd

Tags: grub2

I found a sata drive, a semi-broken hdd power supply and an esata cable lying around, so I decided to install Arch on it.

So I have sda which has the MBR and grub2 (burg) and then another hdd (below). Burg is installed under Ubuntu 12.10.

The drive is formatted with a GPT. Here is parted's output:

```
(parted) print                                                            
Model: ATA MAXTOR STM316081 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdd: 160GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name  Flags
 1      1049kB  3146kB  2097kB                     bios_grub
 2      3146kB  21,5GB  21,5GB  ext4
 3      21,5GB  160GB   139GB   ext4
```

grub legacy told me during the Arch install that a 2MB partition (partition 1 above) is required for GPT drives. It doesn't seem to have a filesystem so I can't mount it.

Now I am trying to chainload Arch's grub from grub2 because I could never really get os-prober to work properly with anything.

This is the grub2 menuentry in burg.cfg:

```
menuentry "Arch Linux (esata hdd, usually /dev/sdd)" --class arch --class os {
    insmod ext2
    set root='(hd3,2)'
    set OS_Boot_config='/boot/grub/grub.cfg'
    multiboot /boot/grub/i386-pc/core.img
}
```

The first problem here is that, as far as grub2 is concerned, (hd3,2) doesn't exist. `ls` in the grub2 console gives `(hd0,msdos1) (hd2) (hd3)`. In other words, grub2 can't see the partitions on sdd. What can I do about this?

The second problem is that grub legacy claims to have installed core.img to the partition 1 (without a filesystem). I don't know how to mount that, so I am using core.img from the root partition. I have no idea if this is correct, should I change this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fixed it, the reason is quite silly. You need the line `insmod part_gpt` so that it recognises the GPT. I've never seen this anywhere on the interwebs.

Comment: Thank you. I had the same issue. A small addition: "insmod part_gpt" goes into "grub.cfg". I guess this issue is so rare because people use "grub.cfg" generated by some utility program.